# Arch linux install mysql access denied error

Tags: mysql, linux, localhost, root

After this command:

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

I recieve this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To address this, you'll want to reset your mysql root password:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/156280/1045-cannot-log-in-to-the-mysql-server